# Why function adding class in jQuery is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add class to 'a' tag on click on 'li' tag. It's my first time using jQuery so probably I'm missing something

```js
$('.nav-item').click( function() {
   $(".nav-item a").removeClass("active");
   $(".nav-item a").addClass("active");
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" href="#">Left</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Right</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What **should** it do? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I believe the problem is that he removes and add the same class to all elements. so visual he see no changes.

Comment: `$(".nav-item a")` selects *all* links, so you're removing the class from all, then adding it to all.

Comment: I'm trying to Add 'active' class to clicked element and remove it from other elements

Comment: Please add all such information to your question by editing it. What makes you think that succeeding calls of `$(".nav-item a")` yield different elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(".nav-item a")` will select all nav-items use `$(this)` to get the selected item,
then it will select the clicked `.nav-item` then you can use `find()` to select a child, So `$(this).find("a")` will select the `a` of the clicked `.nav-item`

*Snippet*

```js
$('.nav-item').click( function() {
   $(".nav-item a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).find("a").addClass("active");
} );
```

```css
.nav-item a{ text-decoration:none; color:blue; }
.nav-item a.active{ color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" href="#">Left</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Right</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `$("a",this).addClass("active");` and not `$(".nav-item a").addClass("active");` because right now you are setting the class `active` to all `<a>`

`this` refers to the element you click, and `$("a",this)` means that you are looking for the element `a` inside of the element that you clicked on.

**Demo**

```js
$('.nav-item').click(function() {
  $(".nav-item a").removeClass("active");
  $("a",this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
a.active{
color:black}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" href="#">Left</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
  </li>
```